# Adding / summing values without the first one

Tags: php

so I am editing my website which has been created by a company but never finished and I have a problem with my price calculator.

Basically it adds every single value from a to b. I need it to add everything without the starting value. Ill paste some code for clarification.

Basically what this script does is sum every single value in chosen range. I need it to sum it without the starting value chosen by the user.

```
    $rank[4][5] = 4;
    $rank[4][4] = 5;
    $rank[4][3] = 6;
    $rank[4][2] = 7;
    $rank[4][1] = 8;
    $rank[5][5] = 9;
    $rank[5][4] = 11;
    $rank[5][3] = 13;
    $rank[5][2] = 15;
    $rank[5][1] = 16;
    $rank[6][1] = 19;
    $rank[7][1] = 20;

    if($ce == 'rankval1')
        $starting = 1;
    else if($ce == 'rankval2')
        $starting = 2;
    else if($ce == 'rankval3')
        $starting = 3;
    else if($ce == 'rankval4')
        $starting = 4;
    else if($ce == 'rankval5')
        $starting = 5;
    else if($ce == 'rankval6')
        $starting = 6;

    if($de == 'rankval1')
        $end = 1;
    else if($de == 'rankval2')
        $end = 2;
    else if($de == 'rankval3')
        $end = 3;
    else if($de == 'rankval4')
        $end = 4;
    else if($de == 'rankval5')
        $end = 5;
    else if($de == 'rankval6')
        $end = 6;
    else if($de == 'rankval7')
        $end = 7;

    $this->price = 0;
    //$starting = 1;
    //$end = 3;
    for($i=$starting; $i<=$end; $i++) {
        if($i == 6 || $i == 7) {
            if($starting != $i) 
                $this->price += $rank[$i][1];
        }
        else    
        if($starting == $end) {
            for($j=$starting_points; $j>=$end_points; $j--) {
                $this->price += $rank[$i][$j];
            }
        }
        else if($i==$starting) {
            for($j=$starting_points; $j>=1; $j--) {
                $this->price += $rank[$i][$j];
            }
        }
        else if($i==$end) {
            for($j=$end_points; $j<=5; $j++) {
                $this->price += $rank[$i][$j];
            }
        }
        else {
            for($j=5; $j>=1; $j--) {
                $this->price += $rank[$i][$j];
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55099589/edit) then the `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] It is very unclear what you mean by "Without the starting value"

Comment: You have tagged the question as JavaScript but the code looks like PHP. Can you confirm which it is?

Comment: This appears to be PHP. I don't think JS has the `->` operator

Comment: its PHP, sorry I am quite new

Comment: by saying without the starting value i ment that the in the current state code adds every single value FROM starting value to ENDing value. And I need it to add everything besides the FROM value. Since now the users chooses from and end values and gets incorrect price which is too high because it adds the FROM value as well

Comment: I'm a little confused, generally when you want to add a bunch of values together, you would want the starting value included in your sum.  However, if it makes sense to not include, why don't you just change your first for loop to for($i=$starting+1; $i<=$end; $i++) {